# Vulkaninfo output errors on Nvidia

Tags: drivers, nvidia, vulkan

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 and my graphics card is Nvidia. I have installed the vulkan driver and the `vulkaninfo` output shows the following:

```
ERROR: [Loader Message] Code 0 : /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvulkan_intel.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
ERROR: [Loader Message] Code 0 : /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvulkan_radeon.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
==========
VULKANINFO
==========

Vulkan Instance Version: 1.2.154


Instance Extensions: count = 18
===============================
VK_EXT_acquire_xlib_display            : extension revision 1
VK_EXT_debug_report                    : extension revision 9
VK_EXT_debug_utils                     : extension revision 2
VK_EXT_direct_mode_display             : extension revision 1
VK_EXT_display_surface_counter         : extension revision 1
VK_KHR_device_group_creation           : extension revision 1
VK_KHR_display                         : extension revision 23
VK_KHR_external_fence_capabilities     : extension revision 1
VK_KHR_external_memory_capabilities    : extension revision 1
VK_KHR_external_semaphore_capabilities : extension revision 1
VK_KHR_get_display_properties2         : extension revision 1
VK_KHR_get_physical_device_properties2 : extension revision 1
VK_KHR_get_surface_capabilities2       : extension revision 1
VK_KHR_surface                         : extension revision 25
VK_KHR_surface_protected_capabilities  : extension revision 1
VK_KHR_wayland_surface                 : extension revision 6
VK_KHR_xcb_surface                     : extension revision 6
VK_KHR_xlib_surface                    : extension revision 6
```

Is it a bug if vkcube shows a normal rotating cube?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't really a bug and is a known [issue](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Loader/issues/262).  The short story is that the Vulkan loader tries to load every driver installed on the system so that it can report information about each driver back to the application.  In this case, `vulkaninfo` is a 64-bit process, and attempting to load 32-bit drivers generates these messages.